# How to trigger onclick event only in the child div element but not in the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, event-handling, dom-events

- I have a div element (parent element)(DIV1), which print the its name when onclick event gets triggered.
- DIV1 has a child div element(DIV2) and it should print its name when onclick event triggered.
- I have applied onclick on window also.

But when I click DIV2, it triggers onclick event of DIV1, so it print the name of parent div(DIV1) instead of DIV2.

So how do I make sure that when I click DIV1 it should trigger DIV1 onlick and when I click DIV2 it should trigger DIV2 onclick?

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Capture the click on DIV2, and prevent propagation. See https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

Comment: It depends on how you have written html code for it, there should be distinction between the two divs else it'll be difficult for dom which div you gonna click

Comment: Please provide the code when asking a question and at least you can provide a image of the arrangement of divs for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the propagation of click event of div2 to div1

```js
const clickHandler = (e,str) => {
e.stopPropagation()
console.log(str)
}

document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click',e=>clickHandler(e,'div1'))
document.getElementById('div2').addEventListener('click',e=>clickHandler(e,'div2'))
```

```html
<div id="div1">
div 1
  <div id="div2">
div 2
  </div>
</div>
```